# Creating a words game in Java(Issues with dictionary File organisation)

Tags: java, android

I tried creating a words game in Java which refers to a text file(.txt) as its main dictionary,English language to be precise.

this dictionary contains about 85,000 words.

I will require an input from the user and check if it is in the dictionary,then if it is,the user gets points for it.

But there is a problem,

1. do i take the 85,000 words in the dictionary and store them in `"Hashmaps`?
2. is there a way for me to check if the string the user entered is inside of the dictionary and the award points for it?

any inputs on this?

Comment: I'm using NavigableSet for similar case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably preferable to load all 85,000 words into a HashSet and check it with contains.

```
Set<String> knownWords = new HashSet<>();
// Populate the set
...
// Check with 
knownWords.contains(userInput);
```

Even cheaper androids generally speaking have at least half a gigabyte of memory which should be able to handle the set (which would be around 3MB at most). The Java HashSet is quite efficient at lookup so the check itself should be fast.

If you want to bring your memory consumption down further, consider calculating some sort of a short hash for each word, splitting the dictionary into multiple files by that hash. Then when the user enters a word, the calculate the same hash for the input, load that file into your in-memory set and evaluate with the same contains method.

(Don't forget to lowercase both the dictionary and the user input)

Comment: Can i use an Array List instead? and store the dictionary words inside and then check with                                                                                            // Check with 
knownWords.contains(userInput);

Comment: You could but you shouldn't. Checking HashSet#contains is essentially a constant time operation (assuming a well behaved hash function) whereas for lists you have to iterate through the entire list to find out if the word was there. With an ordered list you could improve that to O(log n) but it's still  way faster to use HashSets. If you have a separate case where you need to iterate through the words in order consider using something like a LinkedHashSet that provides you with an ordered iterator (specifically one that returns the elements in the order they were put it).